# Bullet alignment issue in outlook windows app

Tags: outlook, alignment, html-lists, html-email

I have html email template and there is an `<ul>` tag.The bullets of the list does not align properly in outlook windows app but it works fine in the browser.

[image]

It needs to be pulled in either to left align exactly or even just within the left margin and should work in both app and browser.

```
<table class=\"test\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"25\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
    <tr>
<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" style=\"padding-top: 5.25%; padding-right: 5.25%; padding-bottom: 5.25%; padding-left: 5.25%;\">
    <ul style=\"margin-left: 20px; padding-left: 0;\">
        <li style=\"font-family:'open sans'; color: #252525; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; margin:0 0 5px 0;\">
                Test content 1
        </li>
        <li style=\"font-family:'open sans'; color: #252525; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; margin:0 0 30px 0;\">
                Test content 2
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Giving 2px more to `<ul>` margin-left is fine for the app but not for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [lists.cm](https://lists.cm/), it's a tool that helps you create bullet lists that work in all email clients.

Alternatively, you could just use tables and `<td>`'s instead for each `<li>` - all email clients support padding on them, so you don't need client-specific hacks. Downside is that you will lose semantics for screenreader users.

Answer (score 0):

Margins and paddings are a bit all over the place with email clients. There are defaults, and Outlooks tend NOT to work with `<ul>` / `<ol>` margins. So you have to use margins in the `<li>`.

Furthermore Gmail webmail will set a margin-left on the `<li>`.

It's best to reset everything if you want consistency. Use the following, and only change the margins in the `<li>`.

```
<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
li {
    text-indent:-1em;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<ul style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <li style="margin:0 0 5px 30px;padding:0;">Point 1</li>
    <li style="margin:0 0 5px 30px;padding:0;">Point 2</li>
    <li style="margin:0 0 30px 30px;padding:0;">Point 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
```